# MongoDB PartialFilterExpression filter issue

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of items where a document looks something like this:

```
{
    "source" : "rest",
    "serviceCode" : "fluff",
    "fluff" : "puff",
    "systemEntryTime" : ISODate("2018-05-16T09:04:00.585Z")
}
```

I have an index with a TTL option for two weeks :

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "systemEntryTime" : 1
    },
    "name" : "systemEntryTime_1",
    "ns" : "storage.item",
    "expireAfterSeconds" : NumberLong(1209600)
}
```

Now I want certain documents where source = "ftp" to have a different TTL. For this purpose I created the following index with a partialFilterExpression:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "systemEntryTime" : 1,
        "source" : 1
    },
    "name" : "systemEntryTime_1_source_1",
    "ns" : "storage.item",
    "expireAfterSeconds" : NumberLong(1),
    "partialFilterExpression" : {
        "source" : {
            "$eq" : "ftp"
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is not working, what am I doing wrong here? I have experimented with dropping the old index and using only this, but no documents a dropped according to the TTL (or any documents at all for that matter).

Comment: Show an example of what you are expecting and what you presently get. Showing documents as viewed from the `mongo` shell is a clear format for everyone to see and use the data in order to replicate.

Comment: I expect items with source "ftp" to be deleted by mongo, but they are not. I don't know how else to describe the issue.

Comment: I updated the question with examples, hope this helps! :)